# How do i cut out a shape from multiple objects with different fills?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to cut out some text out of a rectangle made up of different objects with different patterns as fillings so that I end up with the text in negative space, but whatever I try, it doesn't work. I tried clipping mask, pathfinder, making a mask and inverting it. Nothing seems to work. In the picture, you can see the artboard with the shapes filled with patterns. In black the text that I want to cut out. I already changed the text into outlines. All help and tips are welcome!

[image: Screenshot of the artboard]

Comment: You want the text in negative you say? Why not just make it white? Or do you want the patterns to only be visible inside the letters?

Comment: I want to print it on a white shirt. So I need a file that is just one collor and everything that needs to be white has to be negative space

Comment: Take it easy! I guess your printer wants a PNG file where non-printed areas are 100% transparent and the printed areas filled with the same blue as we see in the question. The text OWC should be transparent too (=shirt fabric with no printed color). Right?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/106031/mask-a-shape-in-front-of-many-small-shapes-in-illustrator-cc and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25818/how-to-punch-through-all-the-layers-in-adobe-illustrator

Answer (score 1):

Should be fairly simple:

I've got similar artwork -

[image]

Convert text to outlines by selecting the text, and going to Type > Create outlines

[image]

Then go to Transparency menu (if you don't have it open, you can find it by going to Window > Transparency)

[image]

You'll have to group any background layers together, and then group any transparency layers together like the below.  Transparent layer will need to be on top.

[image]

Select both groups and click "Make Mask"

[image]

Play with the "Clip" and "Invert mask" options until you get it right.  I have to deselect "Clip" and select "Invert mask" to show the transparency layer as transparent against the background.  (By default, masks show black is transparent and white is visible).

[image]

Now when you export as PNG, the white area will show as transparent - see below.

[image]

Good luck.